# Putting a PHP table in a table

Tags: php, html-table, echo

I have a table which is "pulled" from a MYSQL DB and users can use the dropdown boxes and save to MYSQL. All of it works- but the table doesn't fit the DIV and looks an awful mess. Is there a away I can have a horizontal scroll bar to scroll across the table?

How can I put this table in a table that is 1100x545 px ...it will overflow, but it needs to fit the div. And I would like it to over flow horizontally

```
echo "<table style=\"float:left;\" width=\"130\" border=\"0\" >";
                foreach($Data as $Item => $Value) {
            if(!is_numeric($Item) && $Item !== "UserIDHere") {
                if($i == 0) {
                    $Unit = substr($Item, 0, 2);
                    $Assignment = substr($Item, 2, 2);
                    $Task = substr($Item, 4, 2);

                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$UArr[$Unit]."</p></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$AArr[substr($Item, 2, 2)]."</p></td></tr>";
                    echo "<tr><td width=\"60\">".$TArr[$Task]."</td><td width=\"50\">".DropDown($Item, $Value)."</td></tr>";

                }
                if($Unit !== substr($Item, 0, 2)) {
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<table style=\"float:left;\" width=\"150\" border=\"0\" >";
                    $Unit = substr($Item, 0, 2);
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$UArr[substr($Item, 0, 2)]."</p></td></tr>";
                }
                if($Assignment !== substr($Item, 2, 2)) {
                    $Assignment = substr($Item, 2, 2);
                    echo "<tr style=\"text-align: center\"><td colspan=\"4\"><p>".$AArr[substr($Item, 2, 2)]."</p></td></tr>";
                }
                if($Task !== substr($Item, 4, 2)) {
                    $Task = substr($Item, 4, 2);
                    echo "<tr><td width=\"60\">".$TArr[$Task]."</td><td width=\"50\">".DropDown($Item, $Value)."</td></tr>";
                }
                $i++;
            }

        }
        echo "</table>";
```

The CSS of this is

```
.full-segment
{
    width: 1100px;
    height: 545px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

How do I make it so the overflow is horizontal ) so you slide horizontal and not vertically?

[image: how it's looking]

Comment: Where is closing of corresponding div?

Comment: The DIV needs to be outside the TABLE. And you'll probably want to use `overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: hidden;` or vice versa, depending on where the overage is.

Comment: This hides the Y scroller (YAY!) but how can I make it so it overflows horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `<div>` outside the scope of the `<table>`. So your code should look like:

```
echo "<div foo='bar' foo2='bar2'>
<table foo='bar' foo2='bar2'>";
//populate the table here
echo "</table></div>";
```

<s>The default CSS setting of `overflow:auto` will take care of the rest.</s>

EDIT: The default CSS setting is **not** `overflow:auto`. It's `overflow:visible`. My mistake. You need to declare `overflow:auto` explicitly in the `style` attribute.

UPDATE: Making the fields go horizontally requires putting them into the same `<tr>` tags. Each different `<tr>` tag will result in a new row (on a new line) in the table. For that, you'll want to rethink your grouping and how you're placing those `<tr>` tags, and how many fields you want in one row. Unfortunately, that's something you'll have to experiment with yourself until you find the right look for you.

Also, tables within tables, while they work, can cause loads of trouble if you don't close them properly. You probably want to make sure that that piece of code is doing what you want it to do.

Comment: when I place it outside the table it messes up my whole website as it is metro themed with `divs` being the different 'pages'

Comment: You could try placing another table around it `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="width: 400px; height: 200px; overflow-x:scroll;">`[...]`</td></tr></table>` changing width/height as necessary

Comment: @SetSailMedia doesn't make a difference :/

Comment: is there anything on the `<table style=\"float:left;\" width=\"130\" border=\"0\" >` line that can incorporate the `overflow` ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can try adding `overflow:auto` to the `style` attribute, but I highly doubt that'll work. And as far as I'm aware, the only way to add a scroll bar is using `overflow`.

Comment: I've included it in the page's CSS but still nothing

Comment: Are you able to add `overflow:auto` to the div that the table currently belongs under (i.e., the div that defines the 'page')? Since you said that divs are individual 'pages', that should mean that you can get at their styling.

Comment: I try do it, but it messes with the JQuery.. When I add a `<div>` any further elements no longer act as pages

Comment: Then you are essentially boned. If you can't group the table into a `<div>` that you can apply `overflow` to, then you can't make it show a scroll bar.

Comment: I have been able to make it show a scroll bar, but its grey and does nothing

Comment: `<div title="Tracker">
      <div class="foo" overflow:"auto";>
 
      <?php include"tracker/default.php" ?>
      </div>`  ..ive tried that, but still no luck

Comment: UPDATE- now have overflow visible.. see my amened screenshot please :)

Comment: @Rsmithy See "UPDATE" in answer.

Comment: everything was horizontal until it 'overflowed' :/